# How to create a slider replicate, wp7, c#, silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, slider

I don't necessarily want to use the slider control but rather make the whole screen an interactive slider. For example, I'm practicing on a nightstand app and I'd like it so they can slide their finger down to lower the brightness or up to increase the brightness. I know this has been done in other apps but I'm not sure where to start. If someone could give me a starting point on what technique would work or any ideas in accomplishing this it would be great!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GestureListener from [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). Take a look at sample application provided with SL Toolkit. There is a sample page GestureSample.xaml. You will find there how to detect gestures.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use [Manipulation events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). So, for example, you get the starting position in the [ManipulationStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationstartedeventargs%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event's [ManipulationOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationstartedeventargs.manipulationorigin%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property . You can then get the final position in the [ManipulationCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulationcompletedeventargs%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) event's Manipulation property. Substract the two `Y` components and check if it's greater than or less than zero. If it's greater than zero, the user has moved downwards otherwise they've moved upwards.

```
private void LayoutRoot_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    startY = e.ManipulationOrigin.Y;
}

private void LayoutRoot_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     endY = e.ManipulationOrigin.Y;

     if(endY - startY > 0)
        MessageBox.Text("Down")
     else 
        MessageBox.Text("Up"); 
        //add check to see if it equals zero in which case the user didn't swipe
}
```

Alternatively, you could perform similar actions with the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) or the [XNA Gestures](http://www.nickharris.net/2010/11/using-touchpanel-for-gestures-in-windows-phone-7/). (They both differ slightly).